# Clicking on failures shows nothing in an HTML generated Junit report

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have a Junit html report that is generated from an ant script with the <junitreport> element. Everything looks great except for when I try to view failures, nothing is enumerated in the appropriate frame. I have to click on the test case itself to view all methods that were tested in order to see the failures. This does not apply to errors, only failures.

Here is a screenshot showing the problem. Again, this only happens with the failed assertions, not with unexpected errors within the tests.

[image: No failures are enumerated when trying to show all failures.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. In order to properly have our Junit3 formatted tests run from Ant using Junit4, I had to add the following method to each of my test cases:

```
public static junit.framework.Test suite() {
        return new junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter(SimpleTest.class);
}
```

The issue with this is that for both failures and errors, the JUnit4TestAdapter adds them as errors. I ended up having to override `Junit4TestAdapterCache.testAssumptionFailure(Failure failure)` and make sure that it ran `result.addFailure(Test, AssertionFailedError)` instead of `result.addError(Test, Throwable)`. I then had to make sure my custom runner ran `RunNotifier.fireTestAssumptionFailed` when a failure (and not an error) occurred.